# WebDriver locate element by combined xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way, how I can to identify two xpath values in one.

I have text located somewhere on web page, on another page it exists in same element, but has different xpath. See below two variants:

```
Variant1: .//*[@id='quote_1']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[2] 

Variant2: .//*[@id='quote_1']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]
```

I'm looking how I can combine these two xpath's to one like the following:

`xpath = Variant1 or Variant2;`

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The XPath union operator `|` is probably what you are asking for**:

```
  .//*[@id='quote_1']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[2]  
|
  .//*[@id='quote_1']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]
```

This XPath expressions selects the union of two nodesets:

- All nodes selected by `.//*[@id='quote_1']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/p[2]`
- All nodes selected by `.//*[@id='quote_1']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/span[2]`